# Official resource on simlish language

Tags: conlang-creation, resource-request

I know that Simlish language is not fully created. It is just a list of words and sentences.
Where can I find the full list (official source)?

**P.S** I wanna create this language as fully created conlang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Font of All Knowledge, [Simlish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simlish)

> worked best as a "language" made up of gibberish words that could not
>   be translated, so that the dialogue's meanings would be left open to
>   the imagination of the player.

and that William Wright, the Sims creator, intended it to be that way.

Here's a good [Youtubeumentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGsbeTV76YI) on the topic. The voice actors, the audio director, they aver that it's gibberish. Meaning or emotion without form: while some words and phrases may have acquired "meanings", it doesn't seem like they've actually acquired "translations".

For example, if an English speaker says *sulsul* means "hello" while a French speaker says it means "bon jour", that doesn't mean hello = good day. All three are greetings, and I think that's rather Wright's point: *sulsul* has acquired universal meaning without actually acquiring a specific translation.